# Grab Post Data Using Only Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I will preface this by saying it is very possible that what I want to do is impossible, but I figured I would ask just in case I am wrong.

I am sending HTTP Post data to a JS file sitting on S3. Using only Javascript I want to access the POST data that I am sending to this file.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using amazon-s3. You can use server side JavaScript, AKA Node.js, but when you use amazon-s3 the JS will not run server side. It will literally send the JavaScript as text and nothing more.

Comment: That's what I was thinking cause if I ran it through <script> in the browser it won't allow post handling.